# How do I use the unload command to export a table to a IXF file

Tags: db2

For a table T in schema S, how do I use the ***unload*** command to export T data into a IXF file? The IBM DB2 documentation isn't very helpful for this simple case.

I am trying to compare performance between the export command and the unload command. This is on DB2 9.7 for AIX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah ok.

If you are referring to the [UNLOAD command](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.ugref/src/tpc/db2z_utl_unload.htm), that is only available on DB2 for z/OS. DB2 LUW does not have an UNLOAD command....except if you purchase IBM's separate product [Optim High Performance Unload](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/optim/high-performance-unload-db2-luw/). (I am assuming you are wishing to use that?)

Optim High Performance Unload uses the [db2hpu command](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2ars/v1r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.datatools.inm.doc/inmuref_comlinesyn.html). And though we do not use the tool where I work, it appears that the syntax you are after is the following:

```
db2hpu -t 'S.T' -d <database-name> -format ixf -m 'filesystem/messages.MSGS' -o 'filesystem/myfile.IXF'
```

Comment: I edited my post. Basically I already use the export command, I want to try an equivalent unload command to compare performance